# How to check if MySQL table has next row from Java/Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I was thinking what is a nice way to check if database has a next row? I have an android app, which is consuming PHP web service and I have MySQL database ('dummy').

```
public class myAwesomeClass extends Activity{
    public void onButtonClicked(View view){
       if (dummy has row){
           //do something
           //and proceed to next row
        }
          else {
          //something else
            }
        }
    }
```

Hos does it work? Is there a "special" query in MySQL, or method in PHP? Or is it possible to do it directly within the app? Examples, suggestions, links - everything is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont check whether the database has a next row but whether the result set you got from the database contain another object.In Java(since you mentioned Android) when you obtained the result from the database in a ResultSet object you can loop through the results and check if it has a next row via ResultSet.hasNext()

Comment: Thanks for reply. If the database contains 7000 objects does it mean ResultSet has to retrieve and hold all of them?

Comment: Only if the sql query is calling to retrive all 7000; its up to you to specify condition of retrieval.